# How do I phrase my sentence correctly (predictions of/from/by)?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I am not an English native and new to StackExchange.

I have difficulties determining the correct wording for a sentence with "predict":

> ... the weather forecast is compared to predictions of/from/by various models.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the ELU site.  It would be helpful if you included the research you've already considered, especially in the case of what is likely an idiomatic expression.  You might find a site such as http://www.advanced-english-grammar.com/list-of-prepositional-phrases.html to be useful,, You may also have better luck with a question like this on our sister site for English Language Learners.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. My research covered a Google search for various examples of how to use predict. They were non conclusive. Examples at https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prediction were not helpful either.

Comment: Isn't '... the weather forecast is compiled from predictions from various models' more likely?

Comment: Thanks, the above sentence is an simplified example. My actual sentence has the same structure but can not be rephrased as suggested. I am sorry for the confusion. My sentence is: "Generally, mock samples are not only ideal to compare predictions of/from/by various models, they ..."